# SSMS shows up in taskbar but is invisible

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I came across this very weird issue today. When I open SQL server management studio it shows up in the task bar but somehow it never appears on my screen, even when I do alt+tab to switch to SQL server window, it still shows up in the list of applications but does not appear when I select this application. It even shows up in Task Manager and I can close it from there. I have also restarted my system but without any success.

Comment: Go through the link  [Application appears in taskbar, but window is not visible](http://saniac.com/application-appears-in-taskbar-but-window-is-not-visible/)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be the issue of position of window.

Comment: This issue not about specific programming. Its an OS issue. Google will give better output than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza: I did further research and it turned out to be the issue of window being hidden somewhere else itself. I have attached another monitor with my laptop and it was appearing in the external monitor and unfortunately that monitor was switched off. I haven't been so foolish in my life before.

Comment: I am having this problem now on windows 10

Answer (score 29):

I had this issue and resolved by
in the application on taskbar
1 --> Shift + Right Click
2 --> Press Maximize

Comment: I'm not seeing any maximize option, is that a hot key?  [edit] I had multiple instances open, maximize option is there if you have just one.

Answer (score 3):

I did further research and it turned out to be the issue of window being hidden somewhere else. I had attached another monitor with my laptop and SQL window was appearing in the external monitor and unfortunately that monitor was switched off. I haven't been so foolish in my life before.

Answer (score 2):

my problem soleved by: Shift + Right Click in profiler on taskbar and Press Maximize

Comment: Shift + Right Click on taskbar and Press Maximize was already given as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877233/73226